# Chrome Extension to replace all links with slightly modified versions of themselves

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm a new guy at writing chrome extensions. So far, I have some pretty simple js as my content_script.js:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    links[i].href = links[i].href.replace((www\.)?imgur.com\/gallery\/, i\.imgur\.com\/);
}
```

and my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Degallerify",
  "description": "This extension will convert all instances of imgur.com/gallery/ links to direct links",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "http://*/*","https://*/*"
   ],
   "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "http://*/*","https://*/*"
    ],
    "js": ["content_script.js"]
  }
]
}
```

The premise is simple, just replace all imgur.com/gallery/ links with direct image links. I checked the regex with an online regex compare and it matches perfectly.

However, when I load the extension it doesn't do anything.

[This is an example of a page with gallery links](https://www.reddit.com/r/jonluca/comments/4h71sk/test_imgurcomgallery_post_for_chrome_extension_im/)

When I load the extension and refresh the page, all the links remain gallery links. Is my regex incorrect? Do I need to do something differently for JS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is not concatenated to replacement string, replacement string is not surrounded by quotes; `.` and `/` do not require escaping. Try concatenating `i` to replacement string, with escape of `.` and `/` characters removed, surrounded by quotes.

```
links[i].href = links[i].href.replace((www\.)?imgur.com\/gallery\/
                , i + ".imgur.com");
```

Comment: It still does not work. Also, I'm not concatenating i - that's the actual URL replacement I'm doing. The new url should be i.imgur.com/LINK

Comment: @JonLuca _"Also, I'm not concatenating i - that's the actual URL replacement I'm doing. The new url should be i.imgur.com/LINK"_ `i` is the index of iteration. No replacement string appears at `js` at original Question? What should "LINK" be ?

Comment: I actually ended up figuring it out - `el[j].href = el[j].href.replace(/(.*)?(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(m\.)?imgur.com\/.*/, data.data.link);`

I had to place the regex within two `/` 

thanks!